# Email accounts with same custom domain and two different email services

Tags: email, dns, cloudflare

Suppose Alice and Bob together own the domain `surname.com`, and want to use email addresses `alice@surname.com` and `bob@surname.com`, respectively. They also want to use different email services, say, mailfence for Alice and startmail for Bob, as Alice uses `alice@mailfence.com` and bob uses `bob@startmail.com`.

In their DNS provider (or designated similar service, e.g. cloudflare), they could set forwarding rules so that `alice@surname.com` forwards to `alice@mailfence.com`, and `bob@surname.com` forwards to `bob@startmail.com`.

This will work for incoming email, but a problem remains for outgoing mail: the messages they send will still appear to come from the addresses `alice@mailfence.com` and `bob@startmail.com` instead of `alice@surname.com` and `bob@surname.com`.

To send from custom-domain addresses, mailfence and startmail each support setting provider-specific MX records on the domain, which would enable that email provider to send as well as receive from the custom domain. However, setting MX records that forward to mailfence will prevent mail from being sent to startmail, and vice-versa; contradictory MX records would be required. So it seems this solution does not work for Alice and Bob to use different email providers.

Is there a solution that enables different accounts from different email providers to both receive and send from the same custom domain?

Comment: (Pure) DNS providing cannot forward  alice@surname.com to alice@mailfence.com; rather, this already requires a mail server specified under an MX record for surname.com that can accept surname.com mail and forward it elsewhere. If your registrar offers that service then they actually setup a MX under the hood.

Comment: In order to send from your favourite domain, you just have to speak SMTP to any Mail server that accepts submissions from you and yo "just" have to persuade them to accept the other domain. Since the service providers for mailfence und startmail don't like to be mistaken for open spam relays, the however won't be easily persuaded to do so. Then again, everybody can just fire up their own little mail server and send from any domain they like and claim to be potus@whitehouse.gov - unless the domain in question has some protection in place (e.g., SPF). But these are listed in DNS and you own...